# Custom Firebase Security Rule

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-security

What needs to be done?

- Everybody can read items.
- Everybody who is logged in can write items to database.
- Everybody can edit the items with his/her uid as author.
- Users logged in via password (not twitter...) are moderators and can edit all items.

The database:

```
{ 
    items: [ 
        {
            title: "some title",
            content: "voila, some content",
            author: {
               uid: "FSDF-SDFSDF-SDFS-SFZE"
            }
        }, {
            title: "some second title title",
            content: "voila, some other content",
            author: {
               uid: "1234-234235-2342-2342"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The rules:

```
"items": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": "auth !== null",

    "$item": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.provider === 'password' or root.child('items/' + $item +  '/author/uid').val() === auth.uid"
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: sorry.. not yet completely... Hadn't the time to finish this yet. Will ask for more when I have time to finish that project. Hopefully soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `newData` server variable to get the `author.uid` property. Then use that to check it against `auth.uid`.

```
"items": {
  ".read": true,
  "$item": {
    ".write": "newData.child('author/uid').val() === auth.uid || auth.provider === 'password'"
  }
}
```

You also had the word `or` in the expression rather than `||`.